# Moving the arrow from the bottom to the left side of the tooltip in the tooltip widget (jQuery UI 1.9)

Tags: jquery-ui, css, transform, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using a speech bubble style tooltip based on the [jquery ui tooltip widget 'Custom Styling' demo](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style), but I'm having trouble properly displaying the arrow when I need it on the left side of the tooltip instead of on the top or bottom.

Can someone help me fix this code (it cuts off the tip and displays too large a section of the arrow)?

```
<style type="text/css"> 

   .ui-tooltip.menu_info {
        max-width: 200px;
    }      
* html .ui-tooltip {
    background-image: none;
}
body .ui-tooltip { border-width: 1px; }
    .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after, .arrow_left_side:after {
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid #999;       

    }       
    .ui-tooltip {
        padding: 10px 12px;
        color: Black;
        font: 8pt "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;   
        max-width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    position: absolute;
    }           
    .arrow_left_side {       
        height: 70px;
        width: 8px;    
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        left: -8px;
    }   
    .arrow_left_side:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 25px;    height: 25px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        tranform: rotate(45deg);
    }
     </style>   
 <script>
$(function() {
    $('.menu_info').tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "left+20 center",
            at: "right center",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).css(position);
                $("<div>")
                        .addClass("arrow_left_side")
                        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                        .appendTo(this);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem Description

The problem is caused by a combination of the CSS transformation and the `overflow:hidden`. The *arrow* is actually a square with width and height that is rotated 45<sup>o</sup>. The default origin point for the rotation is `50% 50%` or `center center` which results in the "arrow" square being rotated around the middle which results in the edges being clipped by the `overflow` property.

It's best shown as an image or [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxtAU/1/) (Webkit only), but the code used to demonstrate the problem is also below.

[image: CSS rotation example]

The 1<sup>st</sup> box shows the starting position of the "arrow" square, the 2<sup>nd</sup> box shows a small rotation around the center point. You can see that the edge is clipped already by the containing block's `overflow:hidden`. The 3<sup>rd</sup> shows a 45<sup>o</sup> rotation which demonstrates the problem you have. The 4<sup>th</sup> adds CSS to move the origin point to `0 25px`, that is `x=0, y=25px` which is the bottom left corner, so you can see a small rotation around this point is looking better. The 5<sup>th</sup> pane shows a full 45<sup>o</sup> rotation around the modified origin. This looks much better and all that is left to do is reduce the width of the container to clip off the right hand side which leaves a left facing arrow. Then some simple CSS positioning to move it into place next to the tooltip content.

#### Solution

The modification needed to your CSS are small positioning changes on the container and the addition of an origin point for the rotation. I realise in the above description that I said an origin of `0 25px` but in practice the arrow was still being clipped on the left side so I moved the origin out to `5px 25px` instead.

```
.arrow_left_side {       
    margin-top: -5px;
    left: -10px;
}   
.arrow_left_side:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 5px 25px;
    /* for brevity, I have not added all the different browser prefix versions of transform-origin. If you need cross browser support, you will need to add these here */
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WhWe9/1/) of the above changes

#### Demo Code

For completeness, here is the code to generate the above image. It's useful to interact with the demo by changing the rotation in the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to see the square rotating in real time.

*HTML*

```
<div class="original"></div>
<div class="original-rotated-a-little"></div>
<div class="original-rotated-forty-five"></div>
<div class="original-with-transform-origin-rotated-a-little"></div>
<div class="original-with-transform-origin-rotated-forty-five"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    margin-left:50px
}
div {
    position:relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;    
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: -8px;
    border:1px dashed red;
}   
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
div.original-rotated-a-little:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
}
div.original-rotated-forty-five:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div.original-with-transform-origin-rotated-a-little:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 5px 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
}
div.original-with-transform-origin-rotated-forty-five:after {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 5px 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for not only providing an answer that works perfectly in every browser and showing me exactly how to implement it, but for also explaining it in a way that really fills in the blanks for me (and in non-geek-speak too :-D) And Chrome DevTools looks like it might be a little more user-friendly than Firebug, so I'm looking forward to checking it out :-)

Comment: Happy to help! I think Chrome DevTools took all the good features from Firebug but then added some Google magic to make it so much better.

Comment: Now I'm even more excited about it :-D